# Grails Spock test isn't saving the object, I suspect it has something to do with static mapping?

Tags: grails

I've been baffled by this behavior for a few hours now. I'm using grails 2.4.2 and spock for testing. I have a domain object like so:

```
class AccRegStrDb implements Serializable {

    BigInteger accountId
    String keyName
    BigInteger indexNumber
    String value

    static mapping = {
        version false
        keyName column: "`key`"
        indexNumber column: "`index`"
        id generator:'assigned',
                composite: ['accountId', 'keyName', 'indexNumber']
    }
}
```

Notice that my class has `static mapping` lines. In my spock test, I'm trying to test a service that saves the object into the DB. I have the following code:

```
@TestFor(AccountRecordService)
@Mock([AccRegStrDb])
class AccountRecordServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "saveValue() of String saves to AccRegStrDb"() {
        when:
            service.saveValue(2000000, "keyName", "string")

        then:
            1 == AccRegStrDb.count()
        }
}
```

My service looks like this:

```
@Transactional
class AccountRecordService {
public void saveValue(Long accountId, String keyName, String value) {
        def test = new AccRegStrDb(
                    accountId: accountId,
                    keyName: keyName,
                    indexNumber: BigInteger.ZERO,
                    value: value
            ).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

On test-app, my assertion fails because the object wasn't saved. No weird errors whatsoever. When I remove the `static mapping` in my class, the assertion passes. What could be wrong? Any help?

:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, by removing `generator:'assigned'` in my domain class. So, it now looks like this:

```
class AccRegStrDb implements Serializable {

    BigInteger accountId
    String keyName
    BigInteger indexNumber
    String value

    static mapping = {
        version false
        keyName column: "`key`"
        indexNumber column: "`index`"
        id composite: ['accountId', 'keyName', 'indexNumber']
    }
}
```